# How to retrieve maximum value of a integer column from access database in java program?

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a project "Hospital Management System" in java swing. Now I have a text field whose value is supposed to be increased by one whenever page loads. It basically contain the value of patient Id. Now I want to retrieve the maximum or last value from database and increase it by one and want to set that value in a text field whose variable is "textField_1". Here table name is "patient" and column name is "patid" and this snippet is written in page load event. Select query is successfully executed but the problem is not fetching the maximum value from the database. Control reached in the if block but it's not printing the value if "i". Please help!!

```
    try
    {
        Connection con;
        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;

        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:hos_man");
        st=con.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery("select * from patient where patid = (select max(patid) from patient);");
        if (rs.next()==true)
        {
            int i=rs.getInt(1);
            i++;
            textField_1.setText(""+i);
        }
        else
        {
            textField_1.setText(""+100);
        }   
        con.close();
        st.close();
        rs.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with just using `select max(patid) from patient`?  Also, this assumes that NO-ONE else will add a new patient after this query...

Comment: Is your problem with the SQL (seems not) or with the display? If with the display, leave the SQL out and try to get this up using only java. If that doesn't work, ask a question about this. My guess would be your Text Field does not show the data it has because it isn't repainted / refreshed.

Comment: Also, you should NEVER catch Exception and then do nothing. Maybe you get an exception in `rs.getInt(1)` (because its not an int, maybe? You select all columns, with no order, who knows whats first, could be the name.) and after that you just ignore that Exception. At least write `e.printStackTrace()` to print the exception to the console. Then paste the exception here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your Query is right, but its bad practice. if you need only `max(patid)` then use this query:

```
select max(patid) from patient
```

Then modify your code like below.

```
try
        {
            Connection con;
            Statement st;
            ResultSet rs;

            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:hos_man");
            st=con.createStatement();
            rs=st.executeQuery("select max(patid) from patient");
            int i=100;
            while (rs.next())
            {
                i=rs.getInt(1);


            }
            textField_1.setText(""+i); 
            con.close();
            st.close();
            rs.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This should work

Comment: why use `while` here? `if` does it the same and is simpler to understand that there will never be a second pass through this.

Comment: Why would I? Its clear what it does. I'm just curious on why you would use while instead of if in this case.